# DTW Algorithm OCT-file

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm, octave

I am trying to create a Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) function, which will calculate the minimum distance between the two signals provided to it. It is based on the following algorithm,

**DTW Algorithm:-**

```
int DTWDistance(s: array [1..n], t: array [1..m]) {
    DTW := array [0..n, 0..m]

    w := abs(n-m)// adapt window size (*)

    for i := 0 to n
        for j:= 0 to m
            DTW[i, j] := infinity
    DTW[0, 0] := 0

    for i := 1 to n
        for j := max(1, i-w) to min(m, i+w)
            cost := d(s[i], t[j])
            DTW[i, j] := cost + minimum(DTW[i-1, j  ],    // insertion
                                        DTW[i, j-1],    // deletion
                                        DTW[i-1, j-1])    // match

    return DTW[n, m]
```

more info [DTW Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Now I was able to create an Octave function of this Algorithm and its working properly.

**Octave Function:-**

```
function dtw_distance = dtw2(a,b)

length_a = length(a);
length_b = length(b);

an=zeros(length_a+1,length_b+1);
an(:,:)=9999;
an(1,1)=0;
cost=0;

#Here we have also implemented the window size.
w=abs(length_a-length_b);

for i=1:length_a
    for j=max(1,i-w):min(length_b,i+w)
        cost=abs(a(i)-b(j));
        an(i+1,j+1)=cost+min([an(i,j+1),an(i+1,j),an(i,j)]);
    end
end

an;
dtw_distance=an(length_a+1,length_b+1);
```

Now the computation time of this code increases as the size of argument increases. Hence I am trying to create OCT file which is written in C++ for faster execution.

**C++ OCT File:-**

```
#include <octave/oct.h>

octave_idx_type getMax(octave_idx_type a, octave_idx_type b){
    return (a>b)?a:b;
}

octave_idx_type getMin(octave_idx_type a, octave_idx_type b){
    return (a<b)?a:b;
}

DEFUN_DLD (dtw3, args, , "Find DTW of two Signals With Window")
{

int nargin = args.length();

if (nargin != 2)
    print_usage();
else
{

    NDArray A = args(0).array_value();
    NDArray B = args(1).array_value();

    octave_stdout << "Size of A is" << A.length();
    octave_stdout << "Size of B is" << B.length();

    if (! error_state)
    {
        octave_idx_type row = A.length()+1;
        octave_idx_type col = B.length()+1;

        Matrix results (row,col);

        for(octave_idx_type i = 0; i <= row ; i++)
        {
            for(octave_idx_type j=0; j<= col ; j++)
            {
                results(i,j)=9999;
            }
        }

        octave_stdout << "row col" << results.dim1() << results.dim2() ;
        octave_stdout << "row end" << results(row,0) ;
        octave_stdout << "col end" << results(0,col) ;

        results(0,0)=0;

        octave_idx_type win = (row>col)?(row-col):(col-row);

        octave_idx_type cost = 0;

        for(octave_idx_type i = 1 ; i <= row ; i++)
        {
            for(octave_idx_type j = getMax(1,i-win) ; j <= getMin(col,i+win) ; j++)
            {
                cost=(A(i)>B(j))?(A(i)-B(j)):(B(j)-A(i));
                results(i,j)= cost + getMin(getMin(results(i-1,j),results(i,j-1)),results(i-1,j-1));

            }
        }
        octave_stdout << "Ans is: " << results(row,col);
        return octave_value(results(row,col));
    }

}

}
```

**Sample Input/Output**

1. **Input** - Arg1: [1 2 3 4 5] , Arg2: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

   **Output:**

   *For Octave Function:* Ans is 3

   *For OCT FIle:* 
   *** Error in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.0.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007f24e81eb0a0 ***
   panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
   *** Error in`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.0.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007f24e81eb230 ***
2. **Input** : Arg1 : A=rand(1,221), Args2: B=rand(1,299)

   **Output**:

   *For Octave Function*: Ans is 72.63

   *For OCT File:*

   *** Error in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.0.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007f57a06ad940 ***
   panic: Aborted -- stopping myself...
   Size of A is221Size of B is299row col222300row end9999col end9999Ans is:1 attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
   save to 'octave-workspace' complete
   Aborted (core dumped)

**My Problem:**

1. First of all what is this double free corruption error I am getting when using OCT files?
2. The answer for Octave file and OCT file is different, whats the error in OCT file which is causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: This project's documentation could help you: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should read how to debug oct files (http://wiki.octave.org/Debugging_Octave#Debugging_oct-files)

Then you'll find this part:

```
Matrix results (row,col);
for(octave_idx_type i = 0; i <= row ; i++)
{
    for(octave_idx_type j=0; j<= col ; j++)
    {
        results(i,j)=9999;
    }
}
```

The Matrix result has dimension row, col but you are writing until `i<=row and j<=col` which is 1 beyond bounds. Try `i<row` and `j<col`

There were so many problems in your code which was too much to describe, here my changes. I've replaces some functions which buildt-in functions:

```
#include <octave/oct.h>

DEFUN_DLD (dtw3, args, , "Find DTW of two signals with window")
{

  int nargin = args.length();

  if (nargin != 2)
    print_usage();

  Matrix A = args(0).array_value();
  Matrix B = args(1).array_value();

  octave_stdout << "Size of A is " << A.length() << std::endl;;
  octave_stdout << "Size of B is " << B.length() << std::endl;

  if (! error_state)
    {
      octave_idx_type n = A.length();
      octave_idx_type m = B.length();

      Matrix results (n + 1, m + 1);

      for(octave_idx_type i = 0; i <= n ; i++)
        for(octave_idx_type j = 0; j <= m ; j++)
          results(i, j) = octave_Inf;
      results(0, 0) = 0;

      octave_idx_type win = abs (n-m);

      double cost = 0;

      for(octave_idx_type i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
        for(octave_idx_type j = std::max(1, i-win) ; j <= std::min(m, i+win) ; j++)
          {
            cost = abs(A(i-1) - B(j-1));
            results(i, j) = cost + std::min(std::min(results(i-1,j),results(i,j-1)),results(i-1,j-1));
          }

      //octave_stdout << results << std::endl;
      return ovl(results(n, m));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a minor edit, using simply abs is causing error whereas std::abs is working.

Comment: Interesting, I had no problem compiling it with "mkoctfile -v -g dwt3.cc". what compiler are you using?